# Converting back to HTML characters

Tags: php, mysql, html

I want to convert a string to HTML entities/special characters so that I can store it into MySQL database. 
Example,

This is the way it is stored in MySQL database.
`V3008-02, WS1 Drain Fitting 1&rdquo; Straight w/Silencer`

and when rendered on the browse it shows 
**V3008-02, WS1 Drain Fitting 1” Straight w/Silencer**

My application built in PHP using phpBMS package. I want to convert the rendered text back to original text so that I can store back to database.

On the side note, which is the best way to store HTML tags in the database ?

Is it

`A &#039;quote&#039; is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt`

or

`A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>`

Regards

Comment: I know there is PHP functions like htmlspecialchars() and htmlentities(). But for some reason it is not converting to HTML entities and special characters.

Comment: post a sample input to the function that does the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php
This is the answer to your problems.

I am not sure how you should store the HTML tags. Obviously you can't store them in their original form, and it is bloated to use them with special entities. I recommend instead linking to a file that can be accessed that holds the HTML in it.

OK, you can store them as such, but you should use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php this function, too.

I don't think it's efficient to store a large block of HTML in the field; I guess it depends on the size.

Comment: 0x90, why can't you store them in the original form?  That's what I recommend.  I don't think having a separate file for each string makes any sense.

Comment: `addslashes` is not recommended.  You should use prepared statements (e.g. `PDOStatement` or `MySQLi_STMT`), or a db-specific function like `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend storing entities in the database at all.  Even for a user field that was to be treated as plain text, I would escape it it immediately before output.

However, here, it seems you have a trusted HTML string (e.g. from a catalog).  So just store it as:

```
V3008-02, WS1 Drain Fitting 1” Straight w/Silencer
```

or:

```
A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>
```

and dump it directly to output.  There's no reason to use even `&rdquo;` because you should be able to include it directly with the Unicode encoding of your choice (e.g. UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

The content should be stored in the database in the original form. For example:

```
<p>this is a paragraph</p>
```

should be stored exactly as:

```
<p>this is a paragraph</p>
```

To make SQL injection impossible just escape the input strings with a proper escape function and sanitize your data (for example if it is supposed to be an integer, do an (int) cast). If you're using a framework this will be done for you by the database layer. I used to also do my own escape functions which are pretty easy to do.

Upon display in an HTML page one should use htmlentities (or for example Zend_View's escape method). There is no imminent reason why one would not accept storing special characters in the database as long as the database accepts them and the content is safely output to prevet XSS and such.

The idea behind my arguments is that content should be "exportable" for any platform/place. So if it's an HTML page you are going to use htmlentities(), if it's a CSV file you're going to use CSV exporting functions to process that text, etc.

Comment: "just escape the input" won't make SQL injection impossible

Comment: Could you supply a way in which properly escaped data will still present an SQL injection risk? And perhaps then downvote...

Comment: `$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']); $sql = "SELECT * from news WHERE id = $id";` then request `?id=1 UNION users etc`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That should perhaps help many people improve their code. I, however, still do not agree that my answer deserved a downvote. Here's the reason: when I escape my input I also mean that an Integer should have (int) cast which will make your SQL injection impossible in my code. Suppose we have a string, then the SQL would have the quotes around your $_GET['id] which again will render useless your attack.

Comment: `when I escape my input I also mean` well I am talking of the answer you wrote. I cannot know what do you *mean.* And your answer is just wrong and misleading one.

Comment: My answer focused on how is data supposed to be stored. Not on what should be the proper data sanitization technique, which is what the questioner has requested.

Comment: You should've pronounced yourself either for or against storing data in its original form, rather than focusing on particular, mot-a-mot sentence.

Comment: Aren't comments especially for this?

Comment: Comments - absolutely positively yes. Downvoting - no!

Comment: If you say so.  I used to think it was a way to quickly scheme through the replies and find the "right" answer.

Comment: It seldom reflect real answer's value. It's subjective by design. There are too few professionals around and too much enthusiasts, to expect anything valuable from these points. Tough I didn't touch this button until your recent comments. My note was plain and simple and I don't see any reason to argue it. Though if it bothers you too much you can make dummy edition to your question, so I'll be able to push it back